# Preview tabs unmerge after a restart

Tags: macos, preview

If I have a Preview window with multiple tabs inside, then after I restart my mac (Catalina version 10.15.7), all the tabs "unmerge" into their own separate windows.

I know how to merge all Preview windows into one window composed of multiple tabs. This is not ideal because sometimes I want to have certain windows kept separate and it is quite annoying to have to manually redo this after every restart. I have reports that this also happens on MacOS Ventura 13.4.1(c)

**Is there a way to stop this from happening?**

Comment: I already have the preference to open all files in one window set but have this problem. `Window -> Merge All Windows` brings all windows into one, but, as OP, it would be nice if Preview remembered the groupings and order across reboots.